# OpenLayers 6 change projection

Tags: openlayers, wms, proj4js

Can someone please clarify how does the `View` object in OpenLayers 6 work as to achieve a projection toggle for a `OSM` and `ImageWMS` layers Map. I would love to understand how to change the projection of the map and all its layers through ideally a CodePen of some sort as I have not been able to find an example so far.

Comment: What examples are you missing here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/?

Comment: In the examples it does not show how the Projection propagates if changed for the view. Suppose I want a simple Mercator to Spherical projection toggle for a map with multiple ImageWMS layers (assuming their APIs support different projections), how would I implement it?

Comment: Create different/separate view with the desired projection and set map's view to that view with the `map.setView` method. This work's without problem if all of map's layers are raster layers. In the case of vector layers you also have to reproject all features of those layers.

Comment: For `Image` layers with `ImageWMS` source would that work? Also when changing the `View` of the `Map` does it propagate across all layers visible or added or how does that work?

Comment: For `Image` layer it would work. And yes, it propagates through all layers visible. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection.html